# Why does “arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management” function does not allows me to input a file path?

Tags: arcpy, python, layers

I want to create a layer file from a shapefile.

When I do...

```
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management('123.0_NYC_PARKS',value+"_"+"NYC_PARKS.lyr", "ABSOLUTE")
```

it works because I have this file opened in the table of contents, but when I do

```
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Value/"+value+"/"+value+"_"+NYCPARKS", value+ "_NYC_PARKS.lyr", "ABSOLUTE")
```

I get told that the file does not exist

> ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Value/123.0/123.0_NYCPARKS does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (SaveToLayerFile).

Answer (score 3):

Because the function is expecting a `Layer` object not a `Layer File` as the first parameter.

From the [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/save-to-layer-file.htm):

> **Summary**
>
> Creates an output layer file (.lyr) from a map layer. The layer file
>   stores many properties of the input layer such as symbology, labeling,
>   and custom pop-ups.
>
> ...
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> SaveToLayerFile(in_layer, out_layer, {is_relative_path}, {version}) 
>
> Parameter Explanation                                         Data Type
> in_layer  The map layer to be saved to disk as a layer file.  Layer
> out_layer The output layer file (.lyr) to be created.         Layer File
> ```

If you want to copy an existing `Layer File`, use the `arcpy.Copy_management` method.

```
arcpy.Copy_management(in_layer_file_path, out_layer_file_path)
```

If you want to create a layer file from a feature class, you need to create a `Layer` first.

```
feature_class = "C:/path/to/shapefile.shp"
layer_file = "C:/path/to/shapefile.lyr"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature_class,"new_lyr")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("new_lyr", layer_file, "ABSOLUTE")
```

Comment: Though i was able to create a file, when i try to add it onto the map I get "the selected layer file is not valid"

Comment: So i did  __arcpy.Copy_management(Parks, value+"_NYC_PARKS.lyr")__ then the .lyr file showed up in file path. However when I wanted to move it over to the map from catalog i got that message.

Comment: What is "`Parks`"? `Layer` or `Layer File`?

Comment: "Parks" is a shape file. I want to create a layer file out of a shapefile.

Comment: That won't work, you'll copy the shapefile to a new shapefile. Suggest you edit your question to say exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know how to ask it because the question acknowledges a problem i've been having. Like you said, i'm able to convert from an object but not from a file path. Thats all i really want and my question shows what has worked and what hasn't.